# How to find file path in github repository?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, github, compiler-errors, xunit

I have a CSV file in my GitHub repository. The program is working fine on my pc, but on Github it's not able to get the file path. I have tried changing it also, but still not working.

My goal is to build and run successfully and get a green tick in the action for that workflow.

https://github.com/Engin-Boot/review-case-s22b1

this is the link to the repository. I need to find the right path for the test file. I'm not able to run the unit test because of this.

Comment: Are you editing the code on Github itself? That's not really recommended. Looks like you have some failing Github Actions, that's what you're asking about? It is tough to see what your problem is. Can you point to something more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding coverage, [the logs](https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/tAx3BYxW1wTg6anvgEb6z7MhViKYmGa5D3myLeHwYhgFBo5amO/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/254/signedlogcontent/3?urlExpires=2020-09-16T06%3A32%3A46.4560233Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=JezP6mKNpYb9fnwZeFSqTzHSjU8s62P4JK3S2PNsD8E%3D) simply mention

```
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3660747Z ---------------------------------
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3661082Z Code Coverage report Analysis...
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3661411Z ---------------------------------
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3661815Z Line-Coverage: [ 0.7757999999999999 ] Branch-Coverage: [ 0.8571 ]
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3662100Z 
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3662456Z Package: Receiver Line-Coverage: 0.7757999999999999
2020-09-15T20:31:34.3662852Z Coverage Check: failed
2020-09-15T20:31:34.5535042Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

That means ther emust be some option to set a code coverage threashold which:

- are set on your workstation
- are not set in the GitHub Actions Dotnet setup environment

For the build, [the logs](https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/tAx3BYxW1wTg6anvgEb6z7MhViKYmGa5D3myLeHwYhgFBo5amO/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/255/signedlogcontent/3?urlExpires=2020-09-16T07%3A01%3A40.9934091Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=aEiwy7NQ6myO7qMPm2Ki6g6QxnhCcPH8XfeZkHXWfiE%3D) includes:

```
2020-09-15T20:32:20.2226804Z ##[group]Run jb dupfinder Review-Case-Study.sln -o=dupreport.xml
2020-09-15T20:32:20.2227674Z [36;1mjb dupfinder Review-Case-Study.sln -o=dupreport.xml[0m
2020-09-15T20:32:20.2273022Z shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
2020-09-15T20:32:20.2273438Z ##[endgroup]
2020-09-15T20:32:22.0286981Z JetBrains Duplicates Finder 2020.2.2
2020-09-15T20:32:22.8609143Z Running in 64-bit mode, .NET runtime 3.1.7 under Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
2020-09-15T20:32:24.5697064Z Using toolset version 16.0 from “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin”
2020-09-15T20:32:25.6516885Z Collecting files to analyze:
2020-09-15T20:32:25.6520970Z   from project 'D:\a\review-case-s22b1\review-case-s22b1\Review-Case-Study.sln'.
2020-09-15T20:32:27.9944744Z 16 files found to analyze.
2020-09-15T20:32:28.2335818Z Duplicates report was written to D:\a\review-case-s22b1\review-case-s22b1\dupreport
```

Even though the command run is `jb dupfinder Review-Case-Study.sln -o=dupreport.xml`... it still write at `D:\a\review-case-s22b1\review-case-s22b1\dupreport`.
`dupreport` instead of `dupreport.xml`